# Class not calling __init__

Tags: python-3.x, oop, object

My class hierarchy overwrites `__new__`, but for one of my subclasses, I want it to work normally.
My hierarchy goes `type`->`MetaClass`->`Class`

This is my code:

```
class Class(MetaClass):
    def __call__(self, *_, **__):
        print(_, __)
    def __init__(self, l):
        print(l)
    def __new__(*cls):
        return cls[0]

test = Class()
```

The last line should cause an error if `__init__` is called, but it isn't, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

`__new__` is not returning an instance of `Class`, so `__init__` won't be called.  [From the `object.__new__` documentation:](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__)

> If `__new__()` returns an instance of `cls`, then the new instance’s `__init__()` method will be invoked like `__init__(self[, ...])`, where `self` is the new instance and the remaining arguments are the same as were passed to `__new__()`.
>
> If `__new__()` does not return an instance of `cls`, then the new instance’s `__init__()` method will not be invoked.

Comment: But my hierarchy doesn't inherit from `object`, also could you provide some code?

Comment: @user189728 yes it does.  If you want the bog-standard `__new__`, then do `__new__ = object.__new__` in your class body.

Comment: I got an error `TypeError: object.__new__(MultiFuncDecorator) is not safe, use type.__new__()`

Comment: @user189728 I guess I'm a little confused about the meaning of "work normally".  What do you actually want this classes `__new__` method to do?

Comment: I just want the `__new__` method in my code to return `Class`

Comment: That's what it does at the moment.  Since `__new__` doesn't return a `Class` instance, but rather the `type` instance that is the `Class` type, `__init__` won't be called.